# Can someone make sense out of "Hard Links and Junctions" article from MSDN?

Tags: windows, ntfs, hardlink, msdn, junction

At [Hard Links and Junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365006%28VS.85%29.aspx) MSDN article one can read the following:

> A hard link is the file system representation of a file by which more
>   than one path references a single file in the same volume. To create a
>   hard link, use the CreateHardLink function. Any changes to that file
>   are instantly visible to applications that access it through the hard
>   links that reference it. However, the directory entry size and
>   attribute information is updated only for the link through which the
>   change was made. Note that the attributes on the file are reflected in
>   every hard link to that file, and changes to that file's attributes
>   propagate to all the hard links. For example if you reset the READONLY
>   attribute on a hard link to delete that particular hard link, and
>   there are multiple hard links to the actual file, then you will need
>   to reset the READONLY bit on the file from one of the remaining hard
>   links to bring the file and all remaining hard links back to the
>   READONLY state.

Can someone make sense out of the above paragraph?
Isn't the statement *attributes on the file are reflected in every hard link to that file* equivalent to the statement *changes to that file's attributes propagate to all the hard links*?
How come **resetting** READONLY bit can *bring the file and all remaining hard links back to the READONLY state*?

EDIT

After reading JdeBP's excellent answer to this question I'm still left with doubts.

I understand there's a partial copy of MFT's `$STANDARD_INFORMATION` entry for each hard link pointing to this entry which according to the answer *isn't even kept up to date unless a hard link is renamed, created, or destroyed*. What does happen when one reads attributes of a hard link? I guess this hard link's copy of `$STANDARD_INFORMATION` is ignored as it might not reflect the current state and attributes are being read directly from the MFT's entry's `$STANDARD_INFORMATION`. Additionally during this process no information is updated as it's not any of operations you listed. Is it so?

> If one sets the R bit off in order to enable deleting a hard link to
>   the file, then (presuming that that wasn't the last link) one has to
>   set the R bit back on again, in whatever way, to make the file
>   read-only again.

Now, I don't get the *presuming that that wasn't the last link* part. I don't see how the link being the last one makes any difference here. There's still a file (MFT's entry) itself and one can change its attributes directly (not through any link). Or is it so that if there's a file there's a link meaning there's no one to one correspondence between MFT's entries and files?

Comment: "Reset" might mean opposite things: a) set to the default ('off') state, or b) re-set to the 'on' state as it has been previously.

Comment: In response to your edit: 1) The original is *also* a link. If you delete the last link, it means the file is gone. 2) Once you ask a question and mark an accepted answer, please do not edit any further questions into the same post. Ask them in comments, or in a separate post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `grawity` says, the second "reset" is either poor writing or an outright mistake.

> Isn't the statement *attributes on the file are reflected in every hard link to that file* equivalent to the statement *changes to that file's attributes propagate to all the hard links*?

No.  The article is stating something that is perhaps too much of an implementation detail for its target readership.  On NTFS, each entry in the MFT can have zero or more `$FILE_NAME` [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff469236%28v=prot.10%29.aspx).  These record the parent directory and the name within that directory for each hard link to the file.  But they *also* record file attribute flags, *even though* those flags are recorded in the MFT entry's single `$STANDARD_INFORMATION` attribute.  The rules are a trifle complex, but briefly put `$STANDARD_INFORMATION` is what matters and the `$FILE_NAME` information isn't even kept up to date unless a hard link is renamed, created, or destroyed — which requires touching the `$FILE_NAME` attributes, and so is the point where the current attribute flags can be propagated to the `$FILE_NAME` attributes.

A developer probably explained the gory details of NTFS to the technical author who wrote the MSDN article.  But they don't actually have any relevance to an end user or even to an applications programer.  These are internal details of how NTFS works.  From the Win32 perspective, a file/directory has exactly *one* set of attribute flags, and updating it is updating it, however that is done.  If one sets the `R` bit off in order to enable deleting a hard link to the file, then (presuming that that wasn't the last link) one has to set the `R` bit back on again, in whatever way, to make the file read-only again.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you change the read-only flag on a link, this change takes effect immediately for all of the file's other links but is not immediately *visible* on those links, e.g., in directory listings or via the `attrib` command.